# Physical Laptop Issues

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, laptop-repair

I have been experiencing some physical issues with my MSI laptop.  Firstly, the bottom-left corner of the frame has separated from the screen.

[image]
[image]

This seemed to be the result of an increasingly loud cracking sound when opening and closing the laptop through its life.  The best explanation I have seen so far is that the hinges may have been fastened too tightly when built.

Shortly after this happened, my screen suddenly acquired a redish tint, and has retained it continually ever since, which can sort of be seen in the above image although it doesn't show up that well.  In this state, a faint imprint of graphics left on screen for a while become "stuck" on the screen.  This persists after rebooting, but gradually fades away with use.  The best explanation I have found so far is that an RBG color controller connector may have become disconnected.

Are these diagnoses correct?  Can the issues be fixed at a repair shop, or is there an easy way to self-repair?  If I do not repair anything, and simply cover the laptop instead of closing it, is it likely that further damage will be done (such as additional color connectors becoming dislodged)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it might be possible to salvage the existing laptop screen, it would require full disassembly and checking all the cables and connectors to the graphics controller for damage or loose connections.  However, that will be costly at a repair shop or if you attempt it yourself you risk rendering the laptop screen completely unusable.  A repair will probably require a new case cover, possibly new hinge assembly and possibly a new display. These can often be sourced by your laptop repair shop or on eBay yourself.  But you are probably looking at several hundred dollars in parts alone.  This begs the question of whether it's better to replace the laptop depending on its age.  Unfortunately, hinge design is a weak point in my many laptops and I've lost more than few over the years to poor hinge designs.